# The size of the operating system iOS

Tags: ios, size, byte, system

how  can I GET The size of the operating system  OF iOS ，Accurate to byte。I want to know exactly the size of the operating system is accurate to byte，if so,I can Identification equipment。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you out I believe...

```
-(float)getFreeSpace{  
float freeSpace = 0.0f;  
NSError *error = nil;  
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfFileSystemForPath:kSongsFolder error: &error];  

if (dictionary) {  
    NSNumber *fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes = [dictionary objectForKey: NSFileSystemFreeSize];  
    NSLog(@"%d",fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes);
    freeSpace = [fileSystemFreeSizeInBytes floatValue];  
} else { 
    //Handle error
}  
return freeSpace;
```

}